# Find the length of a diagonal of a rectangular room of length 5m width 3m and height 2.5m using Pythagorean theorem

Tags: geometry

answer according to book is 6.34m
I couldn't figure which numbers are a^2 or b^2 or c^2 as i'm given 3 numbers

Comment: Hint: the order doesn't actually matter.

Comment: You need to apply it twice.

Comment: Oh! now i get it , unlike right triangle order here doesn't matter, thanks

Comment: In right triangle the order of catheti also does not matter.

Comment: doesn't it matter when we are looking for example for b^2 when we are given the hypotenuse and base length?

Comment: Catheti are the bases. Hypotenuse is not. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathetus

Answer (score 2):

A picture can be worth a thousand words:

[image: Room diagonals]

Apply the Pythagorean theorem twice.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the length of the 'solid diagonal'.
First we need to find the length of the base diagonal. That can be done easily using Pythagorean theorem. $\ \sqrt{5^2 + 3^2} = 6 $.
Now this diagonal is a leg of the bigger right triangle whose hypotenuse is the required solid diagonal. You can see this from @amd's picture.
So apply Pythagorean theorem again.
$\ \sqrt{6^2 + (2.5)^2} = \sqrt{37.25} $.
You can work that out with a calculator.

In general for a cuboid with dimensions a, b and c(order doesn't matter), the solid diagonal is:
$\ \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2} $